# How do I use function keys through the Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: byobu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Through the Windows Command Prompt, pressing a function key just sends an odd string of characters to the bash prompt. But I need to send the actual function key to bash, so I can navigate byobu. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That odd series of characters typically *is* the function key, but you can also fake it with Meta shortcuts and the fact that an escape prefix makes the next key meta.  Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then <kbd>1</kbd> to send <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> which is generally parsed as <kbd>F1</kbd> in many commandline tools, including `byobu`.

Comment: "(arg: 3)" 5 more to go...

Comment: "Faking it" should be entirely unnecessary if `TERM` is set correctly.  Setting `TERM` correctly is the right course of action.